# Py_FindMethod is gone in python3. What should I use instead?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, porting

I'm trying to port the avl module for Python I found on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyavl/) to python3. I managed to get rid of most errors, but I don't find clear information on what to do with

```
Py_LOCAL(PyObject *) avl_tree_getattr(avl_tree_Object * self, char *name)
{
    return Py_FindMethod(avl_tree_methods, (PyObject *) self, name);
}
```

There are some suggestions on a [mailing lists](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-3000@python.org/msg15184.html) to just use `PyObject_GenericGetAttr` instead, but I must confess I don't know the internals of python modules enough to see how I could apply it in this specific case.

Any hint ?

Comment: so avl_tree_getattr function can be dropped altogether ... and what in one's code would I have to pay attention to if I want to know whether it's a "common" case or an "uncommon" one ?

Comment: Look at [xmlparse_getattro](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/137e45f15c0b/Modules/pyexpat.c#l1227) in pyexpat.c. It handles a bunch of special cases and otherwise defaults to `PyObject_GenericGetAttr`. It's the function assigned to `tp_getattro`.

Answer (score 0):

as you said it,
`PyObject_GenericGetAttr` seems to be the solution.

In Pascal it looks like : `Result := PyObject_GenericGetAttr(obj, PyString_FromString(key))`

cf. https://github.com/pyscripter/python4delphi/commit/da1179cd5bb5dc033f7e02fac90db2b4859c4edd#diff-3e36d1a884559dd32bbdd327290b89abR173

In C, it could be something like:

```
`return PyObject_GenericGetAttr((PyObject *) self, PyString_FromString(name))`
```